# Duality between restriction and corestriction

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

In the past months I have been (slowly) studying homological algebra by myself.
I have undestood that many arguments and conceps are "dual" to each other.

Here is my naive question.

> Let $H$ be a subgroup of a group $G$, and let $M$ be a finite $G$-module.
>   Is it true that $res:H^\bullet(G,M)\to H^\bullet(H,M)$ is dual of $cor:H_\bullet(H,M)\to H_\bullet(G,M)$ with respect to $Hom_{\mathbb Z}(\cdot,\mathbb{Q/Z})$?

I can't prove this even in the case of G acting trivially on M.
You may assume this for concreteness.

It is not clear to me even if $res$ is null then $cor$ is null.

Thanks in advance.

PS. The book I'm reading is Rotman's Homological Algebra. 
I want to learn about cohomology of groups.